# How to make such combinations with deleted entries?

Tags: combinatorics

Let us suppose I have $N$ entries labeled as $1,2,...,N$, I want to make several combinations out of such entries by deleting the elements.

1) When no element is deleted then I just have a single combination $1,2,...,N$.

2) When every element is deleted I have a single combination.

3) When every element except 2 elements are deleted then I will have combination like $\{1,2\}$; $\{1,3\}$; $\{1,4\}$; ...$\{1,N\}$, $\{2,3\}$; $\{2,4\}$....$\{2,N\}$;...$\{N-1,N\}$ and the total combinations I got are 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}(N-i).$$ **Please note that I have not repeated any combination for instance, $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,1\}$ are same combinations.**
However, I am facing difficulties in further generalizing. For instance

4)When every element except 3 elements are deleted, like $\{1,2,3\}; \{1,3,4\}$ for this condition I am not able to get a certain expression and same for higher orders.
Is there some generalized expression which has been derived in Combinatorics, which can help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).